# How to add default script to run inside a singularity container?

Tags: docker, anaconda, singularity-container

I am trying to build a singularity container based on a pre-built anaconda2 image isuch as:

```
singularity build --sandbox hmmhc.sif library://shahzebmsiddiqui/easybuild/anaconda2:5.2.0
singularity exec hmmhc.sif python --version
Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Based on that, I have installed the [hmmhc](https://github.com/artyomovlab/hmmhc) program using `singularity shell`. I am wondering how to activate the program internally, e.g. run the below lines internal the image:

```
source ~/anaconda2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate hmmhc
```

So that I can exec it as:

```
singularity exec hmmhc.sif hmmhc-predict --help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add/edit the default run options if you are using a [Singularity definition file](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/definition_files.html#runscript). I recommend this option for reproducibility, but it's not strictly required in this case.

Assuming you followed the install instructions from github, you created a new conda environment for the package. The issue is because that conda environment not being the default environment. You can, instead, install the packages into the base/default conda environment and it will then be available to `singularity exec`.

```sh
# in singularity shell
conda config --prepend channels bioconda
conda install ghmm=0.9 'icu=58.*'
pip install git+https://github.com/artyomovlab/hmmhc#egg=hmmhc

# check the image works as expected
singularity exec hmmhc.sif/ hmmhc-predict --help
```

Comment: Thanks @tsnowlan. I scp-ed the hmmhc.sif to my local server and run the same command `singularity exec hmmhc.sif/ hmmhc-predict --help` but got a message of `/.singularity.d/env/90-environment.sh: line 13: module: command not found`. Do you have some suggestions to solve it?

Comment: Guessing it's trying to use the `module` system common in HPC clusters internally and it's not installed in the image. You can view the contents of that file to see what it's specifically trying to do with: `cat hmmhc.sif/.singularity.d/env/90-environment.sh`